# Eclipse is wrapping the lines even if I'm disabling the wrapping

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 2022.12. For some months, when I'm formatting my Java code, Eclipse is wrapping even if I set the line width to 200 characters. I created a new profile starting from "Eclipse 2.1" and I have disabled the line wrapping by doing this:

[image]

But Eclipse is still formatting like that (after the first parentesis):

```
 final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(
           Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER")));
```

Is it normal (and how to fix it ?) or a bug?

Comment: There are more reasons to wrap a line than width. Expand that *Wrapping settings* section and examine them.

Comment: The small icon with the red cross is because I disabled all the wrap options: "Line wrapping policy: Do not wrap (50 of 50)".

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in Eclipse 2022-12. What does the preview show which is shown to the right of your cropped screenshot? Make sure your new formatting profile is active in your project (_Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Formatter). Please improve your example as your current example is incomplete, does not compile, has only 113 characters without wrapping (which is less than 200 characters), and is indented by only a single space.